# Get command line `adb logcat` output similar to Android studio's built in Android Monitor

Tags: android, adb

So Android Studio has a very useful Android Monitor that shows logs specific to my application and everything going on with it; I've tried a few hours to get a logcat from the adb command line that is similar but I'm not getting even close. Specifically I just want the logs from my application, Info level or better. Thank you for whatever help you can provide.

In other words: what parameters can I add to `adb logcat` in order to see logs similar to what you would see inside the Android Studio, Android Monitor view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
adb shell "logcat | grep filter"
```

"filter" could be "you app pid)", or "the TAG".
Like this:

```
adb shell "logcat | grep 12345)"
adb shell "logcat | grep com.xxx.yyy"
```

If using Windows,you can do this:

```
adb logcat | findstr filter
```

Comment: Using the PID seems to be the closest, using the package name only shows lines that contain the package name (which is much fewer lines). Accepting the answer unless someone finds something closer.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty clear that Android Studio is parsing the logcat output, filtering on PID, _adding_ application name, and displaying in its own format.

Answer (score 2):

With this command you can have the same log style as is in Android studio, in a file.

One shot:

```
 adb  logcat -vD -vthreadtime -vUTC -d > yourfile.txt
```

Continuous:

```
 adb  logcat -vD -vthreadtime -vUTC > yourfile.txt
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `-vD` does? Doesn't seem to be in any documentation I could find.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your device with pc you can see adb log by android monitor in android studio or command like as `adb  logcat -v`. When you close your app, the connection with your app have closed. You have two way to check log:

- in logcat window select No Filter or Edit Filter configuration
- Using keystring, Example Samsung device using *#9900#

Comment: I think OP is asking how to filter the output in the console without using the Android monitor tool.

Comment: @cricket_007 correct, I want the parameters to add to the `adb logcat` from the command line to see output like you see inside the Android Studio IDE